# Google Sheets API v3からv4への移行確認方法

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-engine, google-api, java8

GoogleSheetsAPIv3が2020年3月3日でサービス終了との情報があり、SheetsAPIv4への移行方法のドキュメントも開示されていますが、v4移行対応をしたとして、どのようにすればv3のサービス終了後も問題なく動作することの確認が行えるでしょうか？

当方はAppEngineStandard環境でJava（一部GoogleAppScript）で実装したWebアプリケーションを構築しております。
ビルドパスからgdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar、gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jarを除外した上でビルドエラーとならずSheetsAPI使用箇所が動作すればSheetsAPIv3サービス終了後も問題ないと考えてもよいのでしょうか？

v4が2016年から提供されていたことは知っており、性能改善のために一部はv4を使用していますが、バージョンアップを理由に現在稼働しているサービスの全面改修に顧客より費用捻出をお願いすることが難しくここまで来てしまいました。

どうぞよろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0):

> ビルドパスからgdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar、gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jarを除外した上でビルドエラーとならずSheetsAPI使用箇所が動作すればSheetsAPIv3サービス終了後も問題ないと考えてもよいのでしょうか？

使用とはどういうことを指しているのかわかりかねますが、APIが提供終了と言われているのに、そのAPI（この場合はjar）を除外して、どうして動作するのでしょうか。
ありえない話をされています。
もし除外して動作するのであれば、Spreadsheet APIを使用していないということです。